# Best Practices when matching large number of files against large number of regex strings

Tags: python

I have a directory with several thousand files. I want to sort them into directories based on file name, but many of the file names are very similar.

my thinking is that i'm going to have to write up a bunch of regex strings, and then do some sort of looping. this is my question:

is one of these two options more optimal than the other? do i loop over all my files, and for each file check it against my regexs, keeping track of how many match? or do i do the opposite and loop over the regex and touch each file?

i had though to do it in python, as thats my strongest language, but i'm open to other ideas.

Comment: Unless there are so many files (or regexes) that you can't hold the all the filenames and complied regexes in memory at once, I suspect it won't matter which order you set up your loops.

Answer (score 0):

this is some code i use for a program of mine which i have modified for your purposes, it gets a directory (sort_dir) goes every every file there, and creates directories based on the filenames, then moves the files into those directories. since you have not provided any information as to where or how you want to sort your files, you will have to add that part where i have mentioned:

```
def sort_files(sort_dir):

    for f in os.listdir(sort_dir):
        if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sort_dir, f)):
            continue

        # this is the folder names to be created, what do you want them to be?       
        destinationPath = os.path.join(sort_dir,f) #right now its just the filename...

        if not os.path.exists(destinationPath):
            os.mkdir(destinationPath)

        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(destinationPath,f)):
            at = True
            while at:
                try:
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(sort_dir,f), \
                                os.path.join(destinationPath,f))
                    at = False
                except:
                    continue
        else:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(sort_dir,f), destinationPath)
```

Comment: you could easily `import re` and then `re.find` where i have mentioned, and set destinationPath to what you want.